# How to make a relation beetween a JComboBox and a JList like in a Database(1:toMany)?

Tags: java, swing, one-to-many

i was just wondering how to make a relation like in a DataBase (1:toMany) but this time in Java.

I have a `JComboBox` where I need to insert `NAME` and an `ID` (this one needs to be sorted by natural order(smaller to higher)).

In the `JList` I have the same `ID` as in the `JComboBox`, a date and an amount of money (transactions).

So when I select from `JComboBox` I need to show only those transactions that have the same `ID` in the `JList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) which contains the `name` and `id`.  In this class, it would also contain all the transactions as a `List`

The sort order should be managed by the model, to this end, I'd add all the "name" objects to a `List` and use the `Collections.sort` and `Comparator` APIs to simplify the process

Add all these objects to a `ComboBoxModel` and use a custom `ListCellRenderer` to customise the look for the combobox, see [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details

Use an `ActionListener` on the `JComboBox` to detect when a change occurs, using the selected item, get all the transactions from the "name" object and add them to a `ListModel` (if you're clever, you'd just pass the "name" object to custom `ListModel` and it would extract the details for you).  Again, use a `ListCellRenderer` to customise the look of the `JList` to your needs.

You should also consider using a `JTable` which is better at displaying structured data, see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details.

If the data is been managed by separate entities, the basic process is still the same, `ActionListener` triggers when the user changes the selected item in the `JComboBox`, you extract the `ID` and use to gather the transaction information which would be needed by the `ListModel`...

Comment: for `You should `(also consider) `using a JTable` with one column without/without `JTableHeader` with `RowFilter`

Comment: Start with a POJO which contains the name and id. == robs code for 2D array with JComboBox  and simple Redenrer

Comment: @mKorbel My predecessor liked keeping copious amounts of data in multiple dimensional arrays...no, storage of complex data in arrays is never a good idea, they are to difficult to manage and maintain